# Reading and Writing unicode string in Xerces

Tags: xml, apache, c++11, xerces, xerces-c

I want to read and write Arabic character from XML file on windows platform. My c++ program uses Xerces for XML files. As Xerces documentation noted, it Support Unicode character.
I use

```
xercesc::XMLString::transcode()
```

like

```
xercesc::XMLString::transcode("محمد")
```

method but it returns ???? character. what's the wrong? (In Xerces documentation hints that XMLCh is wchar_t)

Comment: What is it you want to do with the transcoded string?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple. I got it after search. XMLCh is typedef of wchat_t so for some methods like xercesDomParser->parser which takes XMLCh* as argument, if the input is type of wstring use c_str(). For example:

```
parser.parse(input.c_str());
```

If the input is type of string, use XMLString::transcode() method. For example:

```
parser.parse(XMLString::transcode(stringVariable));
```

The opposite side is getting `wstring` as output of xerces methods. You should simply use a `wstring` variable and initialize it. For example `xerces::XMLException::getMessage()` will return the XMLCh* as output. You can treat this like this:

```
wstring test=wstring(xerces::XMLException::getMessage());
```

If you want the string you can again use transcode method like

```
char* test=xerces::XMLString::transcode(xerces::XMLException::getMessage());
```